# insert picture in a table - Latex Overleaf

Tags: tables, graphics, overleaf

I want to have a table of two columns and two-rows, one of the columns I want to put a picture in it, and in the second one I want to put a paragraph

here is my code so far :

```
\begin{tabular}{ | m{5cm}| m{30em}| } 
  \hline
 {laravel.png} & Laravel is a free open-source PHP web application framework with expressive, elegant syntax. Was released by Taylor Otwell and follows the model–view–controller (MVC) architectural pattern and is based on Symfony. This framework attempts to take the pain out of development by easing common tasks used in the majority of web projects, such as:
\newline    Powerful dependency injection container.
\newline    Simple, fast routing engine.
… etc
   \\ 
  \hline
 
\end{tabular}
```

I want it to be like this :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

**Edit:**
Two examples. Both use `graphicx`, `enumitem` and `etoolbox` packages for table body:

- Table with `tabularx` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,
    leftmargin=*,
    label=\textbullet,
    before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}},
    after ={\end{minipage}}
                  }
                            }% end of \AtBeginEnvironment
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|m{44mm}|X|}
    \hline
Lavarell Framework 8.83.9
    &   Description     \\
    \hline
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    &   Laravel is a free open-source PHP web application framework with expressive, elegant syntax. Was released by Taylor Otwell and follows the model–view–controller (MVC) architectural pattern and is based on Symfony. This framework attempts to take the pain out of development by easing common tasks used in the majority of web projects, such as:
    \begin{itemize}
\item   Powerful dependency injection container.
\item   Simple, fast routing engine.
\item   etc
    \end{itemize}   \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- Table with `tblr` environment defined in the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,
    leftmargin=*,
    label=\textbullet,
    before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}},
    after ={\end{minipage}}
                  }
                            }% end of \AtBeginEnvironment
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {Q[l, wd=44mm] X[m] },
              row{1} = {font=\small\bfseries},
             measure = vbox      
             }
Lavarell Framework 8.83.9
    &   Description     \\             
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=m]{example-image-duck}
    &   Laravel is a free open-source PHP web application framework with expressive, elegant syntax. Was released by Taylor Otwell and follows the model–view–controller (MVC) architectural pattern and is based on Symphony. This framework attempts to take the pain out of development by easing common tasks used in the majority of web projects, such as:
    \begin{itemize}
\item   Powerful dependency injection container.
\item   Simple, fast routing engine.
\item   etc
    \end{itemize}   \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit (2):**
Recent LaTeX has in kernel implemented most of definitions provided by `etoolbox` package, so for use `\AtBeginEnvironment` it is not needed to load it anymore.